# Text won't display correct UTF-8 characters from table

Tags: php, utf-8

There's not a lot to explain here, so I'll go straight to the point.
When I "query" the database and select `partname` the characters that should be not latin is displayed like question marks.But the text in the table row is showing all the characters nicely.I have set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and table collation to `UTF-8_lithuanian`.I have no idea what is wrong.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Thank you! 
`$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); ` worked.